# Count cycles in column in Power BI

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Basically I have data coming in from a sensor every few seconds. I'm trying to find a way to:

1. Count the number of cycles in a given period such as  hour/day/week (3 cycles shown in picture)
2. Calculate the total time that the sensor was collecting in a given hour/day/week.

I am working in PowerBI desktop and not sure how to do this in either DAX or Query Editor. Any ideas?

Data example: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/03qP8.png

Comment: If a group of sensor readings starts 11:56:00 and continues through  00:00:05 the next day, does that count as one cycle for each of the two days (and each of the two hours)  or does a cycle only get counted based on the starting time or the ending time?

Comment: What is the total time the sensor was collecting? The sum of the duration of the cycles? The difference between the first reading of the first cycle and the last reading of the last cycle within the specified time period? What if a cycle crosses periods like above comment (11:56:00 to 00:00:05), do we count the time active only in each period (day 1 time for day 2, day 2 time for day 2) or does the total time count for both days (day 1 and day 2 each get same time amt)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for such a late answer.  Don't know if this is relevant still or not.

Here's an example where indexing is used to assign an incrementing index number to each contiguous block of sensor readings.  A count of readings can be obtained by doing a distinct count on this index over whatever periods you wish to describe.

Here I have mocked up several hundred thousand readings taken every 3 seconds with the sensors 'on' for 5 readings and 'off' for 5 readings.

[image]

note that there is some slip between the granular and aggregate numbers, this is the result of cycles that spanned over breaks in periods.

Here is the M Query i used for your reference.  I hope it helps.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Book2.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Date", Order.Ascending},{"Time", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"ShiftList" = {""} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(#"Sorted Rows","Sensor Reading"),1),
    #"ColumnsAndShift" = Table.ToColumns(#"Sorted Rows") & {ShiftList},
    #"ResultSet" = Table.FromColumns(#"ColumnsAndShift", Table.ColumnNames(#"Sorted Rows") & {"Previous Reading"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(ResultSet, each ([Previous Reading] = "")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Sensor Reading] <> ""),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"ResultSet",{"Date", "Time"},#"Added Index",{"Date", "Time"},"Added Index",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Index", {"Index"}, {"Added Index.Index"}),
    #"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Added Index",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Time", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows1",{"Added Index.Index"}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filled Down", "Cycle Index", each if [Sensor Reading] <> "" then [Added Index.Index] else ""),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Previous Reading", "Added Index.Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```